# How callback functions works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactSuperSelect library for my react app and I've found one moment, that I can't understand.

```
<ReactSuperSelect datasource={data} onChange={(item) => console.log(item)} />
```

This console.log will return something like this: `[{id: 'id of selected elem', name: 'name of selected elem'}]`.

But when I'm trying to do the same thing in any other place (I mean not in the scope of ReactSuperSelect component), I'm getting `SyntheticBaseEvents` object.

So, as I understand, onChange event in ReactSuperSelect is something like a callback function, that returns some value and I can use this value in higher scope (correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is: how can I emulate the same behavior in my components?
For example: `<MyComponent onClick={(clickedElement) => console.log(clickedElement)}` and get the result like this `{id: 'id', name: 'anyName'}`.

P.S. I know about `clickedElement.target.value`, but I wanna get custom response instead of `SyntheticBaseEvents`

Comment: It's up to `MyComponent` to call its `onChange` prop with the appropriate payload at the appropriate time. If you want to get the target's value from the actual event, what's preventing you from doing that right now? Please give a [mre] to more clearly illustrate the problem.

Comment: You want to do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8bjnc9?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is really very useful for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: hard to comprehend this

Answer (score 1):

Answer for comments from [coglialoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18235939/coglialoro)

I have to create such components:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ onClick }) => {
  const myItem = {
    id: 'id',
    name: 'anyname',
  };
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(myItem)}>Click</button>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent onClick={(clickedElement) => console.log(clickedElement)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```